# Unix zip: zip multiple folders in to one zip file without creating a top containing folder

Tags: unix, zip

I have a folder like this:

```
-resources

--graphics

--sounds
```

I want to zip graphics and sounds folder into a .zip file named resources.zip, which I will use

```
zip -r resources.zip graphics/ sounds/
```

but when I unzip resources.zip, under /home/me, it will be like this:

```
-home

--me

---resources

----graphics

----sounds
```

I don't want the resources folder created when unzipping, can I do anything when zipping to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's the default behaviour of `unzip`. Unfortunatly there is no way to selectivly ignore the original path of the zipped files. You can, however, tell unzip to ignore any path:

`unzip -j resources.zip`

which would unzip all files into the $pwd. That's probably not what you want. You can achieve your desired result by zipping like this:

`zip -j resources.zip ~/resources/*`

This will create a zip-file that saves all files and directories in ~/resources/ but will junk the path ~/resources/, so on extraction you will only get sounds/ and graphics/.